# Is it possible to quickly cancel resurrection stone?

Tags: god-of-war-2018

When I die sometimes I don't want to use resurrection stone, I want to quickly restart the battle. But instead I have to watch dramatic slow-mo scene how Atreus runs to me. Is it possible to cancel this scene quickly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no in-game way to cancel this animation. However, it is likely faster to reload a save from this point than waiting for the animation to finish. You can do this by hitting triangle on the pause screen.

The sequence is: `Pause, triangle, X, X.` This can actually be faster than the death animation ocassionally.